# Windows 10 Home vs Windows 10 Pro for .NET development

Tags: windows

Are there any limitations for using Windows 10 Home Edition vs Windows 10 Pro on personal laptop for developing web applications using tools such as .NET Framework and .NET Core?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro has better troubleshooting environment and associated tools than Home. I would not use Home for this work.

Answer (score 0):

**For specifically .NET development there should be no limitations**.

It's worth noting, however, that Windows Pro provides a number of advantages that businesses might want to consider. Some of which are mentioned below:

- Managing employee data access with WIP, group policies, AAD single sign on, ...
- protection of data if a device is stolen (bitlocker)
- Allow connections to and connections from remote machines using remote desktop connection (pro only)